# Conditional filter of rows based on the values of multiple variables in previous row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to subset a dataframe to only retain rows for which the value of two variables differ from the value of the previously retained row.

Starting with

```
df<-structure(list(x = c("ARM018", "ARM018", "ARM018", "ARM021", 
"ARM021"), y = c("ARF014", "ARF027", "ARF028", 
"ARF014", "ARF020")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df
```

I would like to obtain

```
df_wanted <-structure(list(x = c("ARM018", "ARM021"), y = c("ARF014", 
"ARF020")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df_wanted
```

because the values of both x and y differ across the two rows

I had assumed that the `lag` function from the `dplyr` package could help 
and that the following code would returned df_wanted yet it does return the expected result

```
library(dplyr)

df_attempt<-df %>% 
  filter(lag(x)!=x & lag(y)!=y)
```

Is there any solution to this using the lag function?

Answer (score 0):

a combination of `dplyr:cumsum` and `dplyr:lag` could do the trick:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  filter(cumsum(x != x[1] & y != y[1]) != 
                lag(cumsum(x != x[1] & y != y[1]), default = -1))

       x      y
1 ARM018 ARF014
2 ARM021 ARF020
```